# Can online games from websites be played in Android?

Tags: chrome-for-android, browser

My nephew and I were playing an old Atari videogame from a website on the PC. He has an Android phone and asked me if he could play it on that. I went to the site on Google Chrome and the game loaded fullscreen correctly, but we don't have any idea how the keyboard keys from the PC can be triggered from the phone's screen, if this is possible.

Is this possible? Can online games from websites be played on Android?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can online games from websites be played in Android? Simply answered, yes. Online browser based games are designed to be OS agnostic and work on any hardware using standard software. That said, because of Android and device limitations, it is with some caveats as you are discovering with things like controls, and in some cases web browser plug-ins, or things like Flash, may not work because of the browser(s) available for Android.

That said, in your specific instance where keyboard controls are required, it might not be possible to play the game without some kind of external device like a keyboard or mouse, which most Android devices support via Bluetooth and some via USB-OTG.